# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named pandas

Tags: python, path

I'm in battle with one error sine yesterday. I checked similar topics on stackoverflow, but nothing worked.

That's my project structure:

[image]

When I type:

```
uvicorn main:app --reload
```

To start fastapi this error occure:

> File ".\main.py", line 2, in 
> from scraper.scraper import Scraper
> File ".\scraper\scraper.py", line 3, in 
> import pandas as pd
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

I have tried to add new PATH in windows, change structure of my project. Do you know hot to handle it?

Comment: open the terminal from your IDE, looks like its pycharm.
Run: `python -m pip install pandas`

Comment: Not that. I got "Requirement already satisfied".

Comment: Is it pycharm or else? are you running main.py from pycharm or somewhere else?

Comment: I run my code in pycharm terminal

Comment: As troubleshoot, try opening a terminal outside pycharm run the pip `python -m pip install pandas`,afterwards run `uvicorn main:app --reload` i guess you will need to also type your path to main file.

Comment: It works, when I try to type in windows cmd. IS it possible to fix this pycharm problem?

Comment: if this solved for you, kindly mark as solved below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not pycharm problem,

when running in pycharm terminal your python runs in venv - which has seperate pip packages (thats the point of venv), but `uvicorn` probably passes the data to local python installation and not the venv.

so now after installing pandas in regular cmd, its installed system wide, and you can try running your command in pycharm too